# how to average the mem values in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to read the values of memory after 5 cycles into an output register in verilog. How do I do that? 
For example if i have a code which looks like this,

```
reg[31:0] mem[0:5];
   if(high==1)
   begin
   newcount1<=count2;
   mem[i]<=newcount1;
   i<=i+1;
   count2=0;
   end
```

After the 5 cycles of operation whatever mem values i get, how do i read them in another output register? and can i perform averaging operation on those 5 cycles? and get a nominal value?

Answer (score 0):

Say Your Memory Data Out is ***mem_data*** and you want it Read out in ***mem_data_out*** with ***Latency of 5 Cycles***.

```
parameter MDP_Latency = 4;
reg [31:0] mem_data_out;
reg [31:0] [MDP_Latency - 1 : 0] mem_data_out_temp;


always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(!reset) begin
        for(int i = 0; i < MDP_Latency; i ++)
        begin
            mem_data_out         <= 'd0;
            mem_data_out_temp[i] <= 'd0;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        for(int i = 0; i < MDP_Latency; i ++)
        begin
            if(i == 0)
            begin
                mem_data_out_temp[i] <= mem_data;
            end
            else
            begin
                mem_data_out_temp[i] <= mem_data_out_temp[i - 1];
            end
        end
        mem_data_out <= mem_data_out_temp[MDP_Latency];    
    end
end
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a look at the posted code:

```
reg[31:0] mem[0:5];
if(high==1)
begin
newcount1<=count2;
mem[i]<=newcount1;
i<=i+1;
count2=0;
end
```

The lack of indentation makes it hard to read, i is not declared. The memory is actually 6 locations, 0 to 5.

You have conditionals and assignment not insides and `initial` or `always` block.

I am not sure what you are doing with count2 but mixing blocking and non-blocking is considered bad practise, it can be done but you must be really careful to not cause RTL to gates mismatch.

User1932872 Has posted an answer using for loops it looks like a valid answer but I think loops at this stage over complicate learning and understanding what you are creating in HDLs. While learning I would avoid such features and only uses them once comfortable with the whole flow.

```
reg[31:0] mem[0:4]; //5 Locations

always @(posedge clk) begin //Clked process assignmnets use non-blocking(<=)  
  mem[0]<=newcount1;
  mem[1]<=mem[0];
  mem[2]<=mem[1];
  mem[3]<=mem[2];
  mem[4]<=mem[3];
end
```

With this structure we can see the pipeline of data though mem[0] to mem[4]. We are implying 5 flip-flops where the output of the first drives data into the next. A combinatorial sum of them all could be:

```
reg [31+4:0] sum; //The +4 allows for bitgrowth you may need to truncate or limit. 
always @* begin   // Combinatorial use blocking (=)
  sum = mem[0] + mem[1] + mem[2] + mem[3] + mem[4];
end
```